# moveit: cannot move interactive marker with IKfast

Tags: rviz, moveit, ikfast, marker, openrave

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
i´ve a problem with ikfast for moveit. i´ve gone trough all tutorials and KDL and Trac_ik are working fine in rviz.
However when i´m using the 3DOF IKfast i cant set the goal position with the marker or interact in any way with the leg with Move Group Interface.
The leg is a simple leg with 3 actors in a row.

when i print `openrave-robot.py <myrobot_name>.dae --info links` i´ve got the following links

```
base_link     0                  
thorax        1     base_link    
leg_center_l1 2     thorax       
coxa_l1       3     leg_center_l1
femur_l1      4     coxa_l1      
tibia_l1      5     femur_l1     
tibia_foot_l1 6     tibia_l1
```

the ik-fast was calclulated with

```
python `openrave-config --python-dir`/openravepy/_openravepy_/ikfast.py --robot=<myrobot_name>.dae --iktype=translation3d --baselink=2 --eelink=6 --savefile=ik_leg1.cpp
```

so it is the exact same problem as in this case https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1c8A-DfghA
but using  "position_only_ik: true" in kinematics.yaml doesnt solve the problem

```
leg_1:
  kinematics_solver: group_kinematics/IKFastKinematicsPlugin
  kinematics_solver_attempts: 3
  kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
  kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.005
  position_only_ik: true
```

I assume that the IK cannot solve for the solution and somehow the srdf **may** be wrong.
I´ve used many configurations in the srdf from assigning only joints and one eef.

```
    <group name="leg_1">
            <joint name="base_joint" />
            <joint name="leg_center_joint_l1" />
            <joint name="coxa_joint_l1" />
            <joint name="femur_joint_l1" />
            <joint name="tibia_joint_l1" />
            <joint name="tibia_foot_joint_l1" />
        </group>
  <end_effector name="leg_1_foot" parent_link="tibia_foot_l1" group="leg_1" />
```

as putting putting everythin in a chain, put the rest in a subgroup

```
    <group name="leg_1">
        <chain base_link="thorax" tip_link="tibia_l1" />
    </group>
    <group name="leg_test">
        <joint name="leg_center_joint_l1" />
        <joint name="coxa_joint_l1" />
        <joint name="femur_joint_l1" />
        <joint name="tibia_joint_l1" />
        <joint name="tibia_foot_joint_l1" />
        <joint name="base_joint" />
    </group>
<end_effector name="leg1eef" parent_link="tibia_l1" group="leg_test" parent_group="leg_1" />
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230473/moveit:-cannot-move-interactive-marker-with-ikfast/) by [PizzaTime](https://answers.ros.org/users/24999/pizzatime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-03-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-30**:
Have you ticked the *Approximate IK* checkbox in the RViz MoveIt plugin UI? I'm not sure just setting `position_only_ik: true` is enough for the RViz plugin. It does influence the programmatic interface, but the interactive marker may be a separate thing.

**Comment by [PizzaTime](https://answers.ros.org/users/24999/pizzatime/) on 2016-03-30**:
Hello,
Yes i´ve tried to allow approximate IK and also set collisions to ignore.

**Comment by [PizzaTime](https://answers.ros.org/users/24999/pizzatime/) on 2016-03-30**:
i´ve tried to use a newer openrave version without any success. do you know if there is a convenient way to test the generated ik?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok so now it runs roughly and very rugged
what have i done?

1. I've installed the recommended version of sympy  as told in this wiki http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_Fast_IK_Solution/Prerequisites
2. i've simplified the dae and used only the arm i want to calculate
3. i've rounded the dae

   rosrun moveit_ikfast round_collada_numbers.py <myrobot_name>.dae <myrobot_name>.rounded.dae 5
4. regenereated the ikfast solution...
   PS: without the correct sympy version is was impossible to generate the ikfast for the rounded.dae

but still it is not usable and i'm still unable to use the move_group_interface to set any valid positions

---

ok i got it :-) problem was finally solved when i changed my urdf model and removed all stl files. the generated ik_fast solver was significant smaller and now everything works perfekt!

---

Originally posted by [PizzaTime](https://answers.ros.org/users/24999/pizzatime/) with karma: 36 on 2016-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nuboter_cc](https://answers.ros.org/users/58433/nuboter_cc/) on 2020-08-22**:
Thank you for your answer, it give me some guidance. But, there are still some qusetions.
I built my robot by SolidWorks, and I export it as urdf. The robot description are some links to the mesh.STL in the urdf.  I meet the same problem as you.
Should I transform mesh.STL to mesh.dae , as your answer? If I should, what I should watch out  in this process?